# gulp test: Error in plugin 'gulp-tslint-log'

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, gulp

I am working on JHipster generated project and I have trouble with running gulp.

I installed all node_modules with npm install and this is my package.json and gulpfile.js:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Description for myapp",
  "private": true,
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/main/webapp/bower_components"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "2.11.2",
    "del": "2.2.0",
    "eslint-config-angular": "0.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "1.0.0",
    "event-stream": "3.3.2",
    "generator-jhipster": "3.1.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-angular-filesort": "1.1.1",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "1.8.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "3.1.0",
    "gulp-changed": "1.3.0",
    "gulp-cssnano": "2.1.1",
    "gulp-eslint": "2.0.0",
    "gulp-flatten": "0.2.0",
    "gulp-footer": "1.0.5",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "1.3.0",
    "gulp-if": "2.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "2.4.0",
    "gulp-inject": "3.0.0",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "2.0.0",
    "gulp-ng-constant-fork": "0.4.1",
    "gulp-notify": "2.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "1.1.0",
    "gulp-rev": "7.0.0",
    "gulp-rev-replace": "0.4.3",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.5.3",
    "gulp-useref": "3.0.7",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "karma": "0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
    "karma-coverage": "0.5.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
    "karma-jenkins-reporter": "0.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.0",
    "karma-script-launcher": "0.2.0",
    "lazypipe": "1.0.1",
    "lodash": "4.6.1",
    "map-stream": "0.0.6",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.7",
    "proxy-middleware": "0.15.0",
    "run-sequence": "1.1.5",
    "wiredep": "4.0.0",
    "xml2js": "0.4.16",
    "yargs": "4.3.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "file-saver": "^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

Package.json file

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rev = require('gulp-rev'),
    templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache'),
    htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    ngConstant = require('gulp-ng-constant-fork'),
    eslint = require('gulp-eslint'),
    es = require('event-stream'),
    flatten = require('gulp-flatten'),
    del = require('del'),
    wiredep = require('wiredep').stream,
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    KarmaServer = require('karma').Server,
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    changed = require('gulp-changed'),
    gulpIf = require('gulp-if'),
    inject = require('gulp-inject'),
    angularFilesort = require('gulp-angular-filesort');

var handleErrors = require('./gulp/handleErrors'),
    serve = require('./gulp/serve'),
    util = require('./gulp/utils'),
    build = require('./gulp/build');

var yorc = require('./.yo-rc.json')['generator-jhipster'];

var config = require('./gulp/config');

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return del([config.dist], { dot: true });
});

gulp.task('copy', function () {
    return es.merge( 
        gulp.src(config.app + 'i18n/**')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.dist + 'i18n/'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + 'i18n/')),
        gulp.src(config.bower + 'bootstrap/fonts/*.*')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.dist + 'content/fonts/'))
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + 'content/fonts/'))
        .pipe(rev.manifest(config.revManifest, {
            base: config.dist,
            merge: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist)),
        gulp.src(config.app + 'content/**/*.{woff,woff2,svg,ttf,eot,otf}')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.dist + 'content/fonts/'))
        .pipe(flatten())
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + 'content/fonts/'))
        .pipe(rev.manifest(config.revManifest, {
            base: config.dist,
            merge: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist)),
        gulp.src([config.app + 'robots.txt', config.app + 'favicon.ico', config.app + '.htaccess'], { dot: true })
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.dist))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist))
    );
});

gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'content/images/**')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.dist + 'content/images'))
        .pipe(imagemin({optimizationLevel: 5, progressive: true, interlaced: true}))
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + 'content/images'))
        .pipe(rev.manifest(config.revManifest, {
            base: config.dist,
            merge: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});


gulp.task('languages', function () {
    var locales = yorc.languages.map(function (locale) {
        return config.bower + 'angular-i18n/angular-locale_' + locale + '.js';
    });
    return gulp.src(locales)
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.app + 'i18n/'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'i18n/'));
});

gulp.task('styles', [], function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'content/css')
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('inject', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'index.html')
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.js').pipe(angularFilesort()), {relative: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app));
});

gulp.task('wiredep', ['wiredep:test', 'wiredep:app']);

gulp.task('wiredep:app', function () {
    var stream = gulp.src(config.app + 'index.html')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(wiredep())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app));

    return stream;
});

gulp.task('wiredep:test', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.test + 'karma.conf.js')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(wiredep({
            ignorePath: /\.\.\/\.\.\//, // remove ../../ from paths of injected JavaScript files
            devDependencies: true,
            fileTypes: {
                js: {
                    block: /(([\s\t]*)\/\/\s*bower:*(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/\/\s*endbower)/gi,
                    detect: {
                        js: /'(.*\.js)'/gi
                    },
                    replace: {
                        js: '\'src/{{filePath}}\','
                    }
                }
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.test));
});

gulp.task('assets:prod', ['images', 'styles', 'html'], build);

gulp.task('html', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
        .pipe(templateCache({
            module: 'shiftworkApp',
            root: 'app/',
            moduleSystem: 'IIFE'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tmp));
});

gulp.task('ngconstant:dev', function () {
    return ngConstant({
        dest: 'app.constants.js',
        name: 'shiftworkApp',
        deps: false,
        noFile: true,
        interpolate: /\{%=(.+?)%\}/g,
        wrap:
            '(function () {\n' +
            '    "use strict";\n' +
            '    // DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, EDIT THE GULP TASK NGCONSTANT SETTINGS INSTEAD WHICH GENERATES THIS FILE\n' +
            '    {%= __ngModule %}\n' +
            '})();\n',
        constants: {
            ENV: 'dev',
            VERSION: util.parseVersion()
        }
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'app/'));
});

gulp.task('ngconstant:prod', function () {
    return ngConstant({
        dest: 'app.constants.js',
        name: 'shiftworkApp',
        deps: false,
        noFile: true,
        interpolate: /\{%=(.+?)%\}/g,
        wrap:
            '(function () {\n' +
            '    "use strict";\n' +
            '    // DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, EDIT THE GULP TASK NGCONSTANT SETTINGS INSTEAD WHICH GENERATES THIS FILE\n' +
            '    {%= __ngModule %}\n' +
            '})();\n',
        constants: {
            ENV: 'prod',
            VERSION: util.parseVersion()
        }
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'app/'));
});

// check app for eslint errors
gulp.task('eslint', function () {
    return gulp.src(['gulpfile.js', config.app + 'app/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failOnError());
});

// check app for eslint errors anf fix some of them
gulp.task('eslint:fix', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.js')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(eslint({
            fix: true
        }))
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(gulpIf(util.isLintFixed, gulp.dest(config.app + 'app')));
});

gulp.task('test', ['wiredep:test', 'ngconstant:dev'], function (done) {
    new KarmaServer({
        configFile: __dirname + '/' + config.test + 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }, done).start();
});


gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('bower.json', ['install']);
    gulp.watch(['gulpfile.js', 'pom.xml'], ['ngconstant:dev']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'content/css/**/*.css', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'content/images/**', ['images']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'app/**/*.js', ['inject']);
    gulp.watch([config.app + '*.html', config.app + 'app/**', config.app + 'i18n/**']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('install', function () {
    runSequence(['wiredep', 'ngconstant:dev'], 'languages', 'inject');
});

gulp.task('serve', function () {
    runSequence('install', serve);
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function (cb) {
    runSequence(['copy', 'wiredep:app', 'ngconstant:prod', 'languages'], 'inject', 'assets:prod', cb);
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

gulpfile.js

After running **gulp test** I got an error:

```
Starting 'wiredep:test'...
[22:11:26] Starting 'ngconstant:dev'...
[22:11:26] 'ngconstant:dev' errored after 96 ms
[22:11:26] Error in plugin 'gulp-tslint-log'
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received null
```

Node version is *v6.10.2* and npm vrsion is *3.10.10*.

Is there any idea how ti fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below command :

> npm install --save gulp-tslint-log

Hope this will work!!